# I can't delete my project on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, user-permissions

I can not delete my project on `Google Cloud Platform` with error

> Not enough permissions.

I tried to find the owner of the project through the command:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy [PROJECT-ID]
```

But it still get error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.get-iam-policy) User [user@gmail.com] does not have permission to access project [PROJECT-ID: getIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission
```

**NOTE:** The PROJECT-ID and user@gmail.com are not real

How to solve?

[screenshot GCloud IAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e10Xh.png)

Answer (score 2):

as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/delete) states, you need to have the `resourcemanager.projects.delete` role assigned in [Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/) (while not being the project's owner)... then executing `gcloud projects delete` would flag that project for shutdown and it would be deleted after a while. just as you would need role `resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy` in order to list the project's `IAM` policies.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
In my case, I can not view the permissions or apply roles/permission.

Comment: @RobsonSouzaCerqueira in this case, you would have to contact the owner or the admin to have this deleted for you. resource manager is quite a powerful role, theoretically able to shutdown a company's data-center... or to bankrupt a company with service fees. and in case you might be the owner, check if you're indeed signed in with the correct account.